# Is spelling the name "Ali" as "Alee" wrong?

Tags: arabic, naming

My surname is Ali and I spell it in two ways: "Ali" and "Alee". But my friend says "Alee" is wrong and I should spell it as "Ali". Why this spelling is wrong? Can anyone help us? I am so curious about this because it is the name of a great personality and I do not want to misspell it.

Comment: Did your friend even bother to explain why he/she thinks the spelling "Alee" is wrong?

Comment: My friend says that 99.99% people spell it as Ali so Alee is wrong

Comment: related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23709/22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, there is no "right or wrong". This is only a matter of convention. علي is an Arabic name. Maybe the first person who wrote it in English use "Ali" and other people followed him. That's all. Another example of this is the spelling of the prophet's name. For decades, we've seen people use the spelling "Mohammed" for the prophet's name. But then years ago the more accurate spelling "Mohammad" was more commonly used to spell the prophet's name.